# iOS load resized image without losing quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsimage, nsimageview

I am trying to load a scaled down version of an image without loading original sized image into memory. To reach this goal I was using [ImageIO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html) framework. However in this case I face unacceptable loss of quality.

[This way](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.com/2013/10/resize-image-without-quality-loss.html) I can re-size my image, however original size has to be loaded into memory.

Is there a way to get good quality lower resolution image without loading large image into memory?

Using apple libraries would be preferable, but if there is no other way, third-party library would also be acceptable.

Comment: Can you speak a little further as to what you attempted with ImageIO? Was it just the thumbnail functionality or did you try something else?

Comment: Yes, it was thumbnail functionality `CGImageRef image = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex (imageSource, 0, otpions);`
Here imageSource is an instance of `CGImageSourceRef` and options are defined in an instance of `CFDictionaryRef`. In options preferred size is set, also kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform and kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways, because the idea is to re-size depending on preferred size, witch can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be Accelerate.framework can help. Use vImageScale_Planar8 to resize image. As I know, this framework supports tiling, probably it will reduce memory required.

Comment: Indeed it does have some advantages, not quit what I was looking for, however since no better solution was provided, this will do. And also lets not let that bounty go to waste :).

Comment: Please, post a comment when you will finish with trying this framework. It's interesting :)